# Casing when creating a Windows service using sc.exe

Tags: windows, service, casing

When I use the command:

sc create "myservice" binPath= "C:\somepath\whatever.exe" DisplayName= **"MyService"** start= auto obj= ".\username" password= password

the service is created as follows:

DisplayName:
myservice

ServiceName:
myservice

As you can see, it completely ignores the casing I specified in DisplayName.

However, if I use the command:

sc create "myservice" binPath= "C:\somepath\whatever.exe" DisplayName= **"My Service"** start= auto obj= ".\username" password= password

the service is created as follows:

DisplayName:
My Service

ServiceName:
myservice

In my first command example what causes sc.exe to ignore the casing of the displayname I specified?  Is there another way to create the service with the specified casing?

From an operations perspective the service names don't matter, but I'm trying to appease someone else's sense of aesthetics.

Comment: Wild guess: because the display name and service name match (except for case) the case from the service name is being used for both.  Try making the service name `MyService`.

Comment: Does seem to work exactly like @HarryJohnston says. Ridiculous. I ended up adding a space to the end of the display name and then it did pick it up.